# get_FIELD_serializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm in a situation where I want to change the serializer field depending on a condition. Where the condition comes doesn't matter but I want to be able to switch between serializer fields as the following example:

```
class EntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # author defined from ModelSerializer

    def get_author_serializer(self):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        GET = getattr(request, 'GET', {})
        if request and GET and GET.get('include_author')=='true':
            author_serializer = UserSerializer()
        else:
            author_serializer = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
                read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
            )
        return author_serialize
```

Of course this doesn't work because `get_FIELD_serializer` doesn't exist, but I'm looking for the simplest solution that can do this.

I've tried writing `author` as a property in a naive attempt but it didn't work.

I am aware that I can write multiple EntrySerializers and use `get_serializer_class` but that is just too much boilerplate code for such a small customization.

Comment: can you add the original version of your serializer?

Comment: This is basically it, just trying to implement such a feature to work on rest.

Comment: If you wish to use this feature in many places, it's better to implement a mixin class.

Comment: Yeah just asking to see if there is already a standard way of implementing it before writing my own.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no builtin DRF way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change a serializers' field based on a condition, you could do something like this.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_author(self, instance):
        # your condition here
        if your_condition:
            return instance.author
        return 'hello'
```

Check the docs for SerializerMethodField

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that thank you but, that would require me to manually serialize the object inside the get_author instead of changing the serializer based on a condition, for 2 options it is doable when when you have multiple conditions for multiple options it gets too much work way too quick.